# Show that if λ is an eigenvalue of a projection matrix P, then λ = 1 or λ = 0

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have question.

If a matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is called a projection matrix if $P^2 = P$. How do you show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a projection matrix $P$, then $\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: You should start using MathJax and not waiting until someone edits your question for you.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$, so there is $v$ such that $Pv = \lambda v$, what can you say about eigenvalues of $P^2$?

Comment: note that $P$ idempotent ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $P$ and $x$ an eigenvector associated to it then
$$\lambda x=Px=P^2x=P(Px)=P(\lambda x)=\lambda^2x$$
so we get $\lambda^2=\lambda$ and the desired result follows.