# If $P \in L(V)$ satisfies $P^2=P$, then eigenvalues of $P$ are $0,1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having trouble showing that $0,1$ are both eigenvalues of $P$ that satisfies the given condition in the title.

I'm asking this because we get a certain result as follows.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $P$.

Then there exists a nonzero $v$ s.t $Pv=\lambda v$.

Thus, we get $P^2v=\lambda Pv$. This implies $\lambda v= \lambda ^2 v$, which impies $\lambda^2=\lambda$, and this implies $\lambda=0$ or $1$.

But, according to many solutions, this result must imply $0,1$ are both eigenvalues of $P$.

I just wonder what is the hidden work behind this. What changes "or" to "and"?

Comment: $I^2=I$ and 1 is the only eigenvalue of the identity.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1393661/1098426

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $P$ is the zero operator then $0$ is the only eigen value. If $P=I$ the $1$ is the only eigen value. But if $P \neq 0$ and $ P\neq I$ then $1$ must be an eigen value: Suppose $0$ is the only eigen value. Then Caley-Hamilton Theorem shows that $P^{n}=0$ for some $n$. But $P^{n}=P$ so $P=0$.  I will let you check that if $0$  also must be an eigen value.  [You may use the fact that $(I-P)^{2}=I-P$].

Comment: Thank you! I want to clarify the "if $1$ is the only eigenvector case." So, since $1$ is the only eigenvector, does $P^2=P$ imply $P=I$?

Comment: @john Right, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your calculations, these are clearly the only possible eigenvalues. However, both of these values need not be "attained". For instance if $P$ is the zero transformation($P = 0$), then $0$ is the only eigenvalue.